# How to use Ramda's useWith

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am implementing a function which performs the following detail-abstracted search, for which this example implementation works:

```
// findRecord :: id → [{id: number}] → {id: number}|null
const findRecord = R.curry((id, list) => R.find(R.propEq('id', id), list));
findRecord(1, [{id: 1}]); // {id: 1}
```

I am trying instead to implement the method using `useWith` ( https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith ):

```
// findRecord :: id → [{id: number}] → {id: number}|null
const findRecord = R.useWith(R.find, [R.propEq('id'), R.identity]);
findRecord(1, [{id: 1}]); // Error('r[u] is not a function')
```

Where am I going wrong?  Am I misunderstanding `useWith`'s signature/usage, and if so would another Ramda function serve me better here?  ("Better" meaning similarly terse even if written in ES5, yet still reasonably accessible to fellow programmers.)

[REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.17.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20[%7Bid%3A1%7D%2C%20%7Bid%3A%202%7D]%3B%0A%0Aconst%20findProject1%20%3D%20R.useWith%28R.find%2C%20[R.propEq%28%27id%27%29%2C%20R.identity]%29%3B%0Aconst%20findProject2%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28id%2C%20list%29%20%3D%3E%20R.find%28R.propEq%28%27id%27%2C%20id%29%2C%20list%29%29%3B%0A%0AfindProject2%281%2C%20data%29%3B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right. The only problem is that the version of the REPL you're using:

> https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.17.1#?const%20data...

is 0.17.1, while the documentation you're reading is for the most recent version, 0.25.0.

You can see the problem if you look at the source code, In 0.17.1, [useWith](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.17.1/src/useWith.js) starts with:

```
module.exports = curry(function useWith(fn /*, transformers */) {
  var transformers = _slice(arguments, 1);
  var tlen = transformers.length;
  // ...
```

That is, the `transformer` functions are expected to be *plain arguments* following the initial `fn`, eg `R.useWith(R.find, R.propEq('id'), R.identity);`. If you use `useWith` like that, then in your 0.17.1 REPL version, it'll work as expected:

```
const findProject1 = R.useWith(R.find, R.propEq('id'), R.identity);
findProject1(1, [{id:1}, {id: 2}]);
```

Output:

```
{"id": 1}
```

But in 0.18.0 and later, the `transformers` are expected to be passed *as an array, in the second argument*, rather than as a list of parameters. See [the source](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.18.0/src/useWith.js):

```
module.exports = _curry2(function useWith(fn, transformers) {
  return curry(_arity(transformers.length, function() {
  // ...
```

The change looks to stem from [this issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1104), among others.

So, either upgrade to a more recent version of Ramda, or use `useWith` by passing in functions as individual parameters, rather than an array. Your code works as expected in 0.18.0+.

Comment: I didn't even notice I was using the old REPL version, which makes me glad I included that link.  It turns out I'm actually having a different problem in the actual project, with pipeP.